# How to send curl kind of request with Laravel HTTP client

Tags: laravel, http, curl

I want to send the below request with the Laravel HTTP client, how can we send it?
API endpoint accepts the below request,

```
curl -X 'POST' 'https://api.upstox.com/v2/login/authorization/token' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'code=<Your-Auth-Code-Here>&client_id=<Your-API-Key-Here>&client_secret=<Your-API-Secret-Here>&redirect_uri=<Your-Redirect-URI-Here>&grant_type=authorization_code'
```

I tried with `withHeaders` but response got failed,

```
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->post('https://api.upstox.com/v2/login/authorization/token', [
            'd' => $data,
        ]);
```

It end up with bad request,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Request data directly to HTTP client.no need to pass `d` since d i curl option .Its not required in Http client laravel.

> -d, --data  Send specified data in POST request. Details provided below.

```
 $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->post('https://api.upstox.com/v2/login/authorization/token',[
          'code'=>'Your-Auth-Code-Here',
          'client_id'=>'Your-API-Key-Here',
          'client_secret'=>'Your-API-Secret-Here',
          'redirect_uri'=>'Your-Redirect-URI-Here',
          'grant_type' =>'authorization_code'
        ]);
```

Ref :  [Request Data](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#request-data)
, [Curl Option](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58)

Also you can avoid with Headers using

```
  $response = Http::asForm()->acceptJson()->post('https://api.upstox.com/v2/login/authorization/token',[
          'code'=>'Your-Auth-Code-Here',
          'client_id'=>'Your-API-Key-Here',
          'client_secret'=>'Your-API-Secret-Here',
          'redirect_uri'=>'Your-Redirect-URI-Here',
          'grant_type' =>'authorization_code'
        ]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it hit almost there, but it threw error from API, ``` This request is not supported by Upstox API - This error is thrown when the API call is not recognized or valid, possibly due to incorrect URL formatting or the presence of unexpected characters in the URL.``` so it seems URL not match with required format. How can we check what URL is formed with this request?

Comment: better check  in postman first. if it works then you can implement it in laravel

Comment: I just check with Postman and found that it gives a token when a request is sent via params instead of body! Thank u for hints

Comment: how about http client ? still error

Comment: it was solved now with the same code. Now it accepts post and returns a token.